# Rails find wifi network of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, network-programming

I would like to add a feature to my rails (5.0.1) application and have it only available on a certain wifi network.

Is there a way of finding out what wifi network the user is on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide quite enough context. The short answer is "probably not how you want to." The long answer is:

1. If you're concerned about what network a user of your application is on, you can use `request.remote_ip` to get the remote IP,
2. If you're concerned about where your application is deployed, you can run a system command to get the current Wifi SSID (or equivalent) and run a check against that

Edit: Per your comment you want the ability to ensure that the user is only using it on your private network.

One way you can do this is to make the application not accessible from the outside world. This is a better question for something like serverfault.com

It's simply not possible to detect what Wifi network name they're connected to from Rails, or from Javascript (exceptions apply). But, you can, with a little sysadmin work, detect that they're connected to an IP within your private network.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't think that's quite what I was looking for.  Maybe a little more detail about what I need to build would help:  we want the application to have a feature that only works when a user is in our office and on our wifi network.  Do you know how I could get the users' wifi network information? Thank you for your help!

Comment: that's doable — I'll edit my answer to reflect that.